# In Klonoa, do I unlock anything by collecting all gems?

Tags: klonoa

In Klonoa, you can collect up to 150 gems in a single run in each level. Once I've collected 150 gems in each level, do I unlock anything new?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part, **no**.  Only the Phantomilians matter.  However, if you collect all 72 Phantomilians, you are rewarded with an extra level.

Collecting all 150 gems in *that* level, rewards you with an extra cutscene after the level is complete.

Also, I'm not sure if this was in the Playstation version, but in the Wii version, collecting all 150 crystals in a stage turns the map icon for the level blue rather than a grey crystal icon which you get if you collect between 130 and 149 crystals.  I don't know if you would consider this an unlockable though since it doesn't technically unlock anything.

Comment: Of all the levels in the game, getting 150 gems in the bonus level is the only one I was hoping to not have to do xD

Comment: In the Playstation version, getting 100 gems earned you a green crystal icon. Collecting all 150 gems earns you a blue crystal icon.

Comment: I remember how hard it was to get all the gems in that level, it was worth it after all the trouble of getting the 72 prisoners.  I added another tidbit of information depending on what version of the game you're playing

Answer (score 1):

No, nothing special happens for getting 150 gems on a level (or all levels).